# why is input behaviour works like this?

Tags: html, css, events, input

In this pen there are an input element with `.on('change')` (or keyup) event handler that prints input value to

```js
$('#input-1').on('change', function() {
  $('.output').text($(this).val());
})
```

```css
.output {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin: 10%
}

#input-1 {
  height: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input-1" type="number">
<div class="output"></div>
```

interesting behavious is if you don't move mouse while pressing 'up' or 'down' arrow event handler won't trigger. Arrows are small and it's not easy not to move mouse every time you press it , but just give it a try and you will see that handler won't trigger every time resulting in sequences f.e. 4 (click up) -> 5(click up, mouse not moved) - 5(click up, same) - 5(click up, same) - 8(click up, mouse moved, trigger worked)

How to trigger handler even when mouse not moved and why is it working like this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**tl,dr;** use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event.

The purpose of `input` event implementation is to transcend having to listen differently based on `<input>` type and based on input method used (keyboard, pointer, touch or device dependent).

---

> The DOM `input` event fires synchronously when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been altered. The event also applies to elements with `contenteditable` enabled, and to any element when `designMode` is turned on.

When you're using the internal `.stepUp()` and `.stepDown()` methods of `type="number"`, even though they update the value of the `input` they don't always trigger a `change` event.
This is easily observable when you keep up or down arrow keys pressed and the value keeps changing (or when you keep the mouse pressed on the arrow, without releasing). It is also the case of dragging the handle of a `type="range"` `<input>` (without releasing). The `change` event only gets triggered when you release the handle but `input` triggers on every change to value.

Your updated example:

```js
$('#input-1').on('input', function() {
  $('.output').text($(this).val());
})
```

```css
.output {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin: 10%
}

#input-1 {
  height: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input-1" type="number">
<div class="output"></div>
```

`input` event [documentation here](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-input).